# Heroku console maximum runtime

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I want to run a several hour process over the a `heroku run console` connection. Is there a maximum runtime or log length that I should be concerned about? Would a rake task be better suited, or does it make no difference as the connection is the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Heroku got back to me with the answer: 1 hour time limit on all `heroku run` items.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any hard limit, but in general if you're running a long process in a remote console it's best to detach the process somehow, so the process won't be terminated if there is a connection issue.  This would also get around any actual limit in place.  Use screen if it is available on Heroku dynos, or else look into how to detach (not just background) processes in your shell.